# How to convert cURL to Guzzle GET

Tags: php, laravel, curl, guzzle

First of all: First question here in Stack Overflow, quite an honor! :D

How do i convert the following curl into Guzzle?

```
curl -u USER_KEY:USER_SECRET https://api.apiexample.com/example/oauth/oauth?grant_type=client_credentials
```

I tried the following, but i kept getting 403 - Forbidden error:

```
    $res = $client->request('GET', 'https://api.apiexample.com/example/oauth/oauth',[
        'auth' => ['USER_KEY', 'USER_SECRET'],
        'header' => [
                'Content-Type' => 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
        ],
        'form_params' => [
            'grant_type' => 'client_credentials'
        ]
    ]);
```

What could be wrong with my code?

Edit: Forgot one thing: This request returns a token that lasts for 30 minutes. Any tip to run this function only when the token is about to expire?

Comment: if you are passing form_params then there is no need for header content-type application/x-www-form-urlencoded, it is set by form_params, also please tell if your auth is basic or digest

Comment: Managed to work on it. The auth is basic, so indeed it doesn't need a header at all, at least on the API i'm working on, it managed to provide me an token to use as Bearer on other requests. Thanks for the tip!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would recommend maybe reformatting your request by putting your constant values in the `Client` object declaration and also wrapping the `request` in a `try-catch` block. The `try-catch` block provides the added benefit that it will help you debug the response. Feel free to alter the catch statement as you wish.

```
$client = new Client([
    'base_uri' => 'https://api.apiexample.com/example/',
    'auth' => [
        'USER_KEY',
        'USER_SECRET'
    ]
]);
try {
    $response = $client->request( 'GET', 'oauth/oauth', [
        'headers' => [
            'Content-Type' => 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
        ],
        'form_params' => [
            'grant_type' => 'client_credentials'
        ]
    ]);
} catch (Exception $e) {
    error_log($e->getCode());
    error_log($e->getMessage());
    error_log(print_r($e->getTrace(), true));
}
```

Comment: Wow haha
Thanks for the answer! I'll reformat to look like this!